# Dictionary-like JSON schema

Tags: json, dictionary, jsonschema

I have a json object that can contain any number of nested objects with certain specification, for example:

```
{
  "Bob": {
    "age": "42",
    "gender": "male"
  },
  "Alice": {
    "age": "37",
    "gender": "female"
  }
}
```

And would like to have a schema looking something like:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "propertySchema": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "age",
      "gender"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "age": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "gender": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that I can turn that into array and push 'name' inside the objects. In that case my schema would look like:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "name",
      "age",
      "gender"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "gender": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I would like to have a dictionary-like structure. Is it possible to make such schema?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`additionalProperties` is your keyword:

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "additionalProperties" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "required" : [
            "age",
            "gender"
        ],
        "properties" : {
            "age" : {
                "type" : "string"
            },
            "gender" : {
                "type" : "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`additionalProperties` can have the following values with different meanings:

- `"additionalProperties": false` No more properties are allowed at all.
- `"additionalProperties": true` Other properties are allowed. This is the default behavior.
- `"additionalProperties": {"type": "string"}` Additional properties (of arbitrary name) are allowed, as long as their value follows the given type (`"string"` here).
- `"additionalProperties": {*any schema*}` Additional properties must satisfy the provided schema, such as the example provided above.

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. I added few lines explaining different meanings of "additionalProperties".

Comment: Thanks @JanVlcinsky for enhancing the answer (although using titles for code excerpts seems a bit excessive for me).

Comment: Feel free to edit it as you prefer. That was the reason I have notified you.  I often use headers to deliver key information in a bit more visual way, but it may feel sometime to much, I agree.